# Creating a link for the test cases in Testlink

Tags: testlink

Is there anyway that I can link the 'testcase A' in testcase B's test description within the same test project in TestLink.

Thanks in adv

Rgds
HH

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Relations" section under the "Step actions". There are 5 types of relations. To simply link one test case to another, you can pick "related to" and type ID of related test case.

http://prntscr.com/55xwud